# Get children from a Structure entry

Tags: structure

I'm new in the Craft CMS world. Today I start so build my first website with Craft.

I have a Structure with 2 Levels. Now I want so get the children from level 2. The level 1 entries are overview-pages for the content in the level 2 pages. I've build 2 entry types. One for the content and one overview pages.

Thx for your help :)
Alexander

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to get the level 2 children for *a specific parent entry*, and you have that entry's [entry model instance](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html) (i.e. you have an `entry` variable, referring to the parent entry), you can use that entry model's `children` property (which returns a pre-baked [entry query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#querying-entries), fetching that entry's child entries only). Add the [`level` parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#level) to only fetch children at the desired level:

```
{% set children = entry.children().level(2).all() %}
```

For "standalone" [entry queries](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#querying-entries), there's also the `descendantOf` parameter. This should be set to the parent entry's ID (you can also pass an entry model, e.g. `entry`):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('yourSectionHandle')
    .descendantOf(entry.id)
    .level(2)
    .all()
%}
```

If you want to fetch entries from a structure section at a certain level, but not limited to children of any particular parent entry, you can append the `level` parameter to your basic [entry query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#querying-entries):

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSectionHandle').level(2).all() %}
```

Note that `level` parameter doesn't necessarily have to be an integer; if you want to fetch entries at any level at or above 2, you can pass a string prefixed with the `>=` operator:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('yourSectionHandle').level('>= 2').all() %}
```

Check out [the official docs for the entry query `level` parameter](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#level) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know how to use descendantOf.